# To check and uncheck checkboxes depend on some condition

Tags: angular

I have this following checkboxes in app.components.html

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="temperature($bd_submain)">Temperature</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox color='primary'>Soil Moisture</mat-checkbox>
```

whenever I checked "temperature checkbox". I have to disable the "soil moisture checkbox" or vice-versa

I have used following thing in app.components.ts

```
temperature(bd_submain){
console.log(bd_submain)
if(bd_submain.checked == true){
var input=document.getElementById("group");
input.disabled = true;
} 
}
```

Comment: does mat-checkbox component implement ControlValueAccessor Interface?

Comment: I advise you to work with Forms and [ReactiveForm](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) in order to manage checkbox and input field easily.

Comment: @JamalSalman I don't know about that

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

HTML:

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="first" >Fisrt</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="second" [disabled]="first"> Second</mat-checkbox>
```

TS:

```
first: boolean = false;
second: boolean = false;
```

So, when you check the first checkbox, second checkbox get disable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206116/discussion-on-answer-by-tushar-to-check-and-uncheck-checkboxes-depend-on-some-co).

Answer (score 0):

Just check for value of the textbox in the if condition:

```
sendit(event)
{ 
  if(event.trim() == ""){ 
     this.first = false;
  }else{
     // Do you work to disable checkbox
  }
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-setvalidators-6q2hjp)